# Why is Powershell not importing the exchange Commandlets after removing all Pssession's and adding a new one?

Tags: powershell

**Context**

I created a little Powershell Script that lets you change between 2 Exchange Server (Pssession to the 2 servers). 
In the `Begin` part of the script I remove all existing pssessions (it's on to the default Exchange 2010 server).

```
    # Remove all Ps-Sesssions
    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Then in the `Process` part I do this:

```
Process
{
    # Choose Server:

    # Default server
    $server = "2010"

    if ($ExchangeVersion -eq "2016") {
        $server = "2217ex0010at01"
    } elseif ($ExchangeVersion -eq "2010") {
        $server = "2217exlimbx01"

    } else {
        Write-Host "Server wurde nicht gefunden, gibt 2010 oder 2016 ein"
    }

    # Add Pssession and import it
    $s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$server/powershell
    Import-PSSession $s -AllowClobber
}
```

**The problem**

When I start up powershell, it imports a pssession to the 2010 server. Everything is working fine. I have all commandlets like `get-mailbox`
But when I run the script like this `Set-ExchangeServer -ExchangeVersion "2016"` everything appears to be fine. But then when I try any exchange commandlet it won't exist.

**What have I tried**

I manually typed in the code I have in the script to import the session to 2016. And thats the weird part. When I'm doing it manually it works and I have all commandlets.

**What could be the cause of this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

I did for myself simple functions to remove the previous exchange sessions, it might help you.

Probably you did'nt remove the `tmp*...` Module...

For On-Premise:

```
Function Remove-LocalExchangeShell
{
if ($LocalSession = Get-PSSession | ? {$_.ComputerName -match 'exchSvrName'}) {Remove-PSSession $LocalSession}
if ($TmpModule = Get-Module -Name tmp*) {Remove-Module $TmpModule}
}
```

For Office365:

```
Function Remove-365ExchangeShell
{
if ($365Session = Get-PSSession | ? {$_.ComputerName -match 'Outlook'}) {Remove-PSSession $365Session}
if ($TmpModule = Get-Module -Name tmp*) {Remove-Module $TmpModule}
}
```

Run the one you need before executing the `New-PSSession`

Comment: I tried the "On-Premise" code in my `Begin` part of the script. It does remove the Pssession and Module as expected. But after importing the new one, I still don't have the `get-mailbox` for example. When I then run `Set-ExchangeServer 2010` (so back to 2010) I still don't have `get-mailbox`.

Comment: `Begin {

            $server2010 = "2217exlimbx01"
            $server2016 = "2217ex0010at01"

            if ($LocalSession = Get-PSSession | ? {$_.ComputerName -match 
    $server2010}) {Remove-PSSession $LocalSession}
            if ($LocalSession = Get-PSSession | ? {$_.ComputerName -match 
    $server2016}) {Remove-PSSession $LocalSession}
            if ($TmpModule = Get-Module -Name tmp*) {Remove-Module 
    $TmpModule}
    }`

Comment: Ok I'm sure now. The problem is that the tmp* module doesn't get imported when the script imports the new pssession with `$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$server/powershell`
        `Import-PSSession $s -AllowClobber`

After the scripts finishes and I try to run `get-module` there is no tmp* module anymore. Now the question is Why?

Comment: I think I fixed it by wrapping the `import-pssession` into an `import-module` statement like so:


`Import-Module(Import-PSSession $s) -Global`

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause is a question of scope.

Try changing `$s =` to `$global:s =` so that the session is available outside of the script.

Comment: Is this the same as doing `Import-PsSession $s -Global` ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, [the `Import-PSSession` doesn't have a `-Global` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Yeah you are right. I found a solution in the last comment from the answer above where I did this:

`Import-Module(Import-PSSession $s) -Global`

But I think this is the same idea, so it's an issue of scope. Thank you sir!